# Using Webrtc and Webspeech API simultaneously

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, webrtc, webspeech-api

Currently I'm using Webrtc to stream both video and audio in Chrome. At the same time I'm using Chrome's Webspeech API to get the audio into text. This work's fine in desktop Chrome but when I try this on Android Chrome, the Webspeech API's `onresult` function doesn't fire if the Webrtc is streaming both video and audio.

Is there a way to have Webrtc streaming both audio and video and have Webspeech recognizing speech at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: did you get any workaround for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not.